# Power BI : Convert Duplicate Table into a Reference Table

Tags: powerbi

Is there an automated way to convert a  Duplicate Table(With all its steps) into a Reference Table preserving all the steps in Query Editor ?

Comment: Whats a duplicate table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, not really, but it's possibly trivial to do manually for one query.

Reference Table and Duplicate Table are GUI operations, which like other GUI operations, simply insert M code into the query. You can see the entire query in the Advanced Editor.

Reference Table just inserts the name of the other query; the effect is branching the data processing pipelines. If you change the original query, it affects all downstream queries.

Duplicate Table copies all of the steps; the effect is creating a separate query. You can change them at any point later. There is no link to where the steps came from even if they aren't changed.

So, it seems that you just want to convert duplicated steps to references. There is no automated way of doing it. But if you know two queries start with the same steps, try this: Duplicate to a base query and remove final steps that are not in common. Mark the new query to not load to the report by: Click All Properties; Uncheck Enable load to report. Then you can replace the duplicated initial steps in the other queries with a reference by a step like `Source = BaseQuery` in the Advanced Editor.

Also, if you find yourself duplicating steps in the middle of a query, you can create a query used as a function.